# Installing Django in virtualenv not working

Tags: django, virtualenv

I want to install Django (just the latest version) inside my virtualenv directory:

`C:\Users\Beheerder\Desktop\Projects\ProjectRango`

Now I did activate my virtualenv and tried:

```
$ pip install django
```

After that the error shows:

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in c:\python34\lib\site-packages
>
> Cleaning up...

which looks like it's trying to install it again inside the main folder instead of inside my virtualenv.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you activate virtualenv properly? Did you use `$ source ./your_new_virtualenv/bin/activate`?

Comment: They are on windows, not sure `source` works on windows.

Comment: first you have to activate the virtualenv. Then you have to install django. Then check in your virtualenv, that django is installed or not?

In windows you can activate venv using this.
..>your venv directory>bin>.activate

Comment: seems not to work :/, and source is not working on windows either :/